# Best way to write a piece of code functional style

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the best way to write a piece of code that makes use of the functional syntax.

**Sample 1:** **looks good**, but a priori is **less efficient**, unless the browser can perform some kind of optimization that avoids the array unwanted to be declared multiple times.

```
var isExcluded = function(e){
   var unwanted = ["orange", "tomato", "apple"]
   return unwanted.indexOf(e) === -1;
}

["orange", "melon", "apple"].filter(isExcluded).
```

**Sample 2:** is **more efficient**, but looks **less tidy** because isExcluded should contains all the logic related to the fact that an element is excluded, while here it's spread over two lines.

```
var unwanted = ["orange", "tomato", "apple"];
var isExcluded = function(e){       
   return unwanted.indexOf(e) === -1;
}

["orange", "melon", "apple"].filter(isExcluded)
```

**Sample 3:** is probably **more efficient**, looks a little **tidier**, but i'd say quite harder to read.

```
var isExcluded = (function(){ 
   var unwanted = ["orange", "tomato", "apple"];
   return function(e){
     return unwanted.indexOf(e) === -1;   
   }

})();

["orange", "melon", "apple"].filter(isExcluded)
```

I was hoping to have some input on theses three methods in terms of which brings the best readability/efficiency ratio.

EDIT:
Please forget about browser support comments, it is not the focus of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.filter()` in conjunction with `Array.prototype.indexOf()` which should both be supported in all current browsers:

```
["orange", "melone", "apple"].filter(function(e) {
    return ["orange", "tomato", "apple"].indexOf(e) != -1;
});
```

Comment: At least I have to unfortunately still support IE8 which seems to have a big chunk of browser market share, and both won't work there. Check UnderscoreJS for fallbacks.

Comment: browser support is not my concern, it's really more of a readability/efficiency question.